# Migration assistant to specific folder

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, data-transfer, file-transfer

I have a 290gb of data on my old mac. It won't boot up. I have a firewire cable and am going to transfer the data to my MacBook pro which has 590gb of free space. I want to use migration assistant, but want all the files from my old mac to be put in one specific folder. Is there a way I could do this with migration assistant, because this is only a temporary solution.

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: you could try the Target Disk mode for that, the old drive acts as slave and the new one as master.

Answer (score 1):

Migration assistant will copy files into expected places on the disk so ~/Library ~/Documents etc and is only meant to be used when installing OSX.

If you want to copy to one directory don't use Migration Assistant. Instead

1. Install OSX from scratch and create a new user (for ease if you have multiple users create them in the same order as before so that their UIDs match) - or just keep the target running current OSX.
2. Connect Macs via firewire and boot up old Mac in Target Disk Mode
3. The old disk is now seen under /Volumes
4. Copy files onto new disk as you want

If step 2 fails then you need to take the disk out of the old Mac and put iy in a USB or other external disk caddy. Then it might work. If the disk is corrupt then look at disk recovery tools or firms.

Comment: I cannot install osx from scratch, I need to keep the MacBook unharmed. Any other ideas?

Comment: Then just do steps 2 onward

Comment: I'm a bit confused, could you elaborate?

Comment: Ahh I see, I have tried that, but the copying fails half way through. I need another solution, copying just from the volume doesn't work for me

Comment: Then I suspect your disk is corrupt - look at disk recovery software or find a firm that recovers data from disks

Comment: No its not corrupt, it's just the permissions that are messed up and it requests a password and sometimes just doesn't allow me to copy. All the files are there, I checked the volume and everythings good.

Comment: These issues should be pout in the question as the problem now looks very different to what is there - how did you check the volume and who owns the files?